# Getting error: undefined variable; what to do?

Tags: php, frameworks, kohana

I use the Kohana 3.2 framework. I have one variable with a static string.
Code for `index.php` controller:

```
 class Controller_Index extends Controller_Template {
    public function action_index()
    { 
      $articles_ = Model::factory('index')->do_magic();
      $view_content = View::factory('index/index')->set('query', $articles_);
      $this->response->body(View::factory('template/index')
        ->set('page_title', 'Sākums')                      
        ->set('content', $view_content));             
    }
} // End Welcome
```

And code for Template controller (`template.php`):

```
class Controller_Template extends Kohana_Controller_Template {
  public $template = 'template/index';
  public function before() 
  {
    parent::before();
    $config = Kohana::$config->load('common');
    $this->template
      ->set('site_name', $config->site_name);
  }
}
```

And my config file (`common.php`)

```
return array (
  'site_name' => 'reGative.id.lv',
)
```

I get the error: `ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: site_name`.
Where is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:
`$this->template
->set('site_name', $config->get('site_name'));`

**Edit:**
After a second look I think you made your life harder. I have simplified your code a little:

```
class Controller_Index extends Controller_Template {
    public function action_index()
    { 
      $articles_ = Model::factory('index')->do_magic();
      $this->template->page_title = 'Sākums';
      $this->template->content = View::factory('index/index')->set('query', $articles_);                  
    }
} // End Index
```

```
class Controller_Template extends Kohana_Controller_Template {  
  public $template = 'template/index';  
  public function before()   
  {  
    parent::before();   
    $this->template->site_name = Kohana::$config->load('common')->get('site_name'); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Does $site_name variable exists in your view?

Comment: Yes, $site_name variable exits in index.php view.